# how to create a dict of numpy array from dataframe

Tags: dataframe, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | row1 |
| Second | row 2 |

And I want to get

```
d = {A:np.array([First, Second], B: np.array([row1, row2]}
```

Have tried df.to_dict(), won't work.

Any quick way to do it?

Comment: what's wrong with `to_dict`?  We don't like to see `doesn't work`

Comment: @hpaulj, it doesn't give the structure I want. I am getting {A: 0 Frist 1 Second, B: 0 row1 1 row2} if I used df. to_dict('series')

Comment: What if you include `inter=False`?  How about iterating on columns, and using a `dict_comprehension` to make the dict, with column names as keys, and column values as the values.  `dict` is a basic python structure, so use basic python tools.  Don't hold out for some magical "vectorized" numpy method.

Comment: This is an X/Y smell. Why do you actually need this? (Hint: if things are going well, you usually shouldn't.)

Comment: @hpaulj, I can iterate columns to do it, but wondering whether there is a quick way doing it. Thank you.

Comment: quick?  There's nothing quick about making a dict.  For what it's worth, I doubt in pandas has a quick (i.e.compiled) method for making the dict.  The 'quick' numpy stuff is all numeric  - working with existing arrays.

Comment: `{k: v.to_numpy() for k, v in df.to_dict("series").items()}` is not good enough for you?